# Django Multiple concurrent logged-in accounts

Tags: django, session, authentication

In the context of a e-health related service, the end-users (health operators, doctors and physiotherapists) working in the same physical environment and sharing just one client PC to interact with my backend, asked me to provide them with a mechanism to quickly switch among different accounts (security is not a concern most of the time because they are used to work within a LAN but, occasionally, they might work from remote clients, so I must keep an authentication/authorization backend in place). They would log in just once and then, before using the web application, would select their logged-in account from a combobox (sort-of).

The UI model might be the same as in GMail where it's possible to keep multiple logged-in user accounts and switch between them through the account selector in the top right corner.

I'm no django-authentication expert, so I am not able to even tell whether this is possible in the context of a django based app.

Does anyone know of any ready-made app/middleware to get this done? Or maybe point me in the right direction if I have to extend or modify existing code?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked for any existing solution for this, so this is how I would go about it from scratch.

You'd need to add storage to the user session to hold multiple users. Currently it looks much like:

```
{'_auth_user_backend': 'membership.auth_backends.MyCustomAuthenticationBackend',
'_auth_user_hash': 'e2c8ecf1e7ecdbd<snip>',
'_auth_user_id': '3806'}
```

and I would add an array to the session:

```
logged_in_users = [{'_auth_user_backend': ... }, {}, {}] # one auth dict per user
```

Then when you "switch users", edit the session object to move that user's auth details (id, hash and backend) into the top-level ones in the session.

You'll also have to write a custom login function that stores the login into the `logged_in_users array`, and takes out the bit in the [current login function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L100) that flushes your session if the key is the same as the session of a different logged in user. Similarly, you'll need to think what happens when you logout.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'll try to follow the suggested approach and let you know if that worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've completed the first draft implementation. I pretty much adopted your strategy, apart from the 'logged_in_users' which became the key of a dictionary instead of a list (so that I can look up for an already logged in user by using its ID).

The only obvious drawback is that I had to modify a private django file (the `__init__.py` you linked at the end) to prevent it from flushing the session as you said. I'm not a huge fan of such an approach, so I'll wait for cleaner solutions before accepting yours. 

Thanks a lot, that's a really a great answer nevertheless!

Comment: Good idea with that change, and yes, I wasn't entirely clear. If you don't want to modify `django.contrib.auth` (and I agree, you shouldn't!), then you should write your own login/logout functions (just copy the existing ones and strip out the session recreation bits), and then use the new functions instead in your views. This could all be spun out nicely into a redistributable app too.

Comment: I must admit that you were extremely clear in the first place: I simply misread that part of your answer. That should work perfectly, so I think I'm going to accept this one in a few more days: the only solution I would prefer wrt this one would be a ready-made app. In case no one is aware of such a thing, I might fill that gap ;-)

Comment: Well, I'm looking forward to it then (and happy to test).